# One SSD and two HDD. Install on SSD and RAID 0/1 or LVM for HDDs?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, system-installation, ssd, raid

I would like to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC, but I'm uncertain on what would be the best for my setup. I have a 128GB SSD (Crucial M4) and two 500GB HDDs.

Currently I'm running Windows 8 where I have Windows installed on my SSD and with the help of [Storage Spaces](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/storage-spaces-pools) I have an additional 1TB D:/ drive.

I kind of wanted a similar (or maybe a completely different but better) setup for Ubuntu. The system should be installed on the SSD (for performance reasons, obviously) and my Documents, Music, Videos, etc. should be stored on the two HDDs.

I thought about using a software raid, as it is described in this [AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/a/217027/143507), also with level 0 or 1 (I don't mind missing 500GB of storage, I don't need that much). I also heard about LVM, but even after researching for quite some time I don't know if would be useful for me and even if, I'm too insecure to set it up.

Now I wanted to ask you for help. Maybe you have a similar setup or just know what would be the best alternative.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit 1: I also have a 500GB external hard drive which I would use for backups.

Comment: are you trying to replace your Windows 8 or dual boot and use both?

Comment: I'm going to replace Windows 8 completely with Ubuntu, no dual booting.

Answer (score 0):

If I had your hardware, and was dropping Windows entirely as you mention in your comment, I would install the operating system on the SSD mounted at / and use the installer options to mount one of the 500GB drives at /home The 2nd 500GB HDD I would likely hold in reserve and mount as needed for backups. I think you'll find you have plenty of space and having a backup plan is always a fabulous idea. You can skip LVM entirely since it's not in your comfort zone and there are always easy ways to deal with outgrowing storage on a Linux system such as Ubuntu.

Full Disclosure: I actually have 3 systems setup exactly like this.

In response to your edit regarding keeping the 500GB internal as a spare or mounting it when you also have a 500GB external that you are using for backup: I would still keep it as a spare and mount it as needed. Say you collect lots of pictures and video and discover one day that one of those folders is taking up half your space. You could mount the spare temporarily on /mnt/whatever, mv all the files from the overloaded folder to the spare drive and then unmount and remount to your original pictures or videos folder. end result is a seamless increase of space where you need it most.

Comment: Ah I should mention that in my post, I also have a 500GB external hard drive which I would use for backing up my data. Would you still leave one disk unmounted as a spare, or use it?